# With the ImageUpload component how to get the file URL from parent REACT class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using REACTJS and the very well known material framework:
https://www.creative-tim.com/learning-lab/nextjs/core-upload/material-dashboard#example-1

I import the component:

```
import ImageUpload from 'components/CustomUpload/ImageUpload.js';
```

I put the code into the render function from the parent class:

```
<ImageUpload avatar/>
```

But how to get the file URL back and to transform the file in base64?

Thank you ;-)

This is the code of the child class:

```
import React from "react";
// used for making the prop types of this component
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

// core components
import Button from "components/CustomButtons/Button.js";

import defaultImage from "assets/img/image_placeholder.jpg";
import defaultAvatar from "assets/img/placeholder.jpg";

export default function ImageUpload(props) {
  const [file, setFile] = React.useState(null);
  const [imagePreviewUrl, setImagePreviewUrl] = React.useState(
    props.avatar ? defaultAvatar : defaultImage
  );
  let fileInput = React.createRef();
  const handleImageChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let reader = new FileReader();
    let file = e.target.files[0];
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      setFile(file);
      setImagePreviewUrl(reader.result);
    };
    if (file) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  };
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // file is the file/image uploaded
    // in this function you can save the image (file) on form submit
    // you have to call it yourself
  };
  const handleClick = () => {
    fileInput.current.click();
  };
  const handleRemove = () => {
    setFile(null);
    setImagePreviewUrl(props.avatar ? defaultAvatar : defaultImage);
    fileInput.current.value = null;
  };
  let { avatar, addButtonProps, changeButtonProps, removeButtonProps } = props;
  return (
    <div className="fileinput text-center">
      <input type="file" onChange={handleImageChange} ref={fileInput} />
      <div className={"thumbnail" + (avatar ? " img-circle" : "")}>
        <img src={imagePreviewUrl} alt="..." />
      </div>
      <div>
        {file === null ? (
          <Button {...addButtonProps} onClick={() => handleClick()}>
            {avatar ? "Add Photo" : "Select image"}
          </Button>
        ) : (
          <span>
            <Button {...changeButtonProps} onClick={() => handleClick()}>
              Change
            </Button>
            {avatar ? <br /> : null}
            <Button {...removeButtonProps} onClick={() => handleRemove()}>
              <i className="fas fa-times" /> Remove
            </Button>
          </span>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ImageUpload.propTypes = {
  avatar: PropTypes.bool,
  addButtonProps: PropTypes.object,
  changeButtonProps: PropTypes.object,
  removeButtonProps: PropTypes.object
};
```

Comment: I don't think this is automatic. You will need to actually upload the image to a server and then get the URL where that image is stored from that server.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, Yes but I need the image to be encoded in base64 and returned to the parent.

Comment: Why do you need to base64 encode the image? Will it be sufficient to upload the image and use its URL to request it?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, There is no server but a websocket protocol. I need to add values from the parent class to build a ws message.

Comment: So you need to send the image over a websocket?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://web.dev/read-files/#read-content) will help?